# Ansible playbook doesn't copy files, does not give error

Tags: copy, ansible

My ansible playbook is only copying one of the files that I have specified. The playbook runs to completion without any errors. If I run the same command outside of a playbook it will copy

My very simple playbook

```
---
- hosts: "dudes"
  vars:
    remote_user: root
tasks:
    - name: Installs logstash-forwarder rpm
      yum: name=logstash-forwarder state=present disable_gpg_check=yes

    - name: Add the certs init and etc files into place
      action: copy src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.crt dest=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ owner=root group=root mode=644
      action: copy src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-etc dest=/etc/logstash-forwarder owner=root group=root mode=644 force=yes
      action: copy src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-etc-sysconfig dest=/etc/sysconfig/logstash-forwarder owner=root group=root mode=644 force=yes
      action: copy src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-init-d dest=/etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder mode=0755

    - name: add logstash forwarder to chkconfig
      command: chkconfig --add logstash-forwarder
      notify:
            - start logstash-forwarder
handlers:
    - name: start logstash-forwarder
      service: name=logstash-forwarder enabled=yes state=started
```

I run the playbook with

```
ansible-playbook -l doozy logstash-forwarder-dudes.yml
```

and it completes without any errors, saying all tasks are OK

The only file that actually gets copied is the last file, which is the logstash-forwarder into init.d. The chkconfig add also seems to work

If I run the command with ansible -m (instead of the playbook) on one of the files that didn't copy before, it will copy them without error

```
ansible -m copy -a "src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.crt dest=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ owner=root group=root mode=644" doozy
```

I'm not sure why the files do not end up getting copied to the desination host in my playbook, but will work by calling the ansible copy module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be multiple actions in Ansible task.

Copy the files in four tasks and it should work:

```
- name: Copy logstash-forwarder.crt
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.crt dest=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ owner=root group=root mode=644

- name: Copy /etc/logstash-forwarder
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-etc dest=/etc/logstash-forwarder owner=root group=root mode=644 force=yes

- name: Copy /etc/sysconfig/logstash-forwarder
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-etc-sysconfig dest=/etc/sysconfig/logstash-forwarder owner=root group=root mode=644 force=yes

- name: Copy /etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder-init-d dest=/etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder mode=0755
```

In the code I've also used [Action Shorthand](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#action-shorthand) and replaced `action: module ...` notation with `module: ...`. It doesn't change the way the code works but is the preferred way to call a module.

Answer (score 0):

Base on answer #1, I added "owner=root" and "group=root" (owner=root was an error, so I changed it to "user=myusername").

No error messages after submission. That is an improvement, but still no file copied on the destination.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).